# WhatsApp Business API - WhatsApp Flow problem sendig payload to endpoint

Tags: whatsapp-cloud-api, whatsapp-flows

I'm developing a Flask app to store data from my clients (Datakinder parents). I am receiving the request and decrypting the message successfully. But I always receive incorrect data
On on-click-action' I expect to receive user typed data but I always receive  ${form.parentname} , not the user data

Footer code is:

```
                        "type": "Footer",
                        "label": "Siguiente",
                        "on-click-action": {
                            "name": "data_exchange",
                            "payload" : {
                                "parentname":"${form.parentname}"
                            }
                        },
                        "enabled":true
                     }
```

At clicked "Siguiente" (next), endpoint receive data={'parentname': '${form.parentname}'} it must be :  data={'parentname': 'Alejandro'}

Any Idea?

I sent fixed data in payload and it was received properly, but form data is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few questions to help debug the issue:

1. Can you check if the Footer component is inside the `children` list of the `Form` component?
2. Can you share a minimal flow JSON to reproduce the issue?
3. How are you testing? On a phone or Flows Builder?

Comment: Thank you!!! you are right Footer component was outside the children list of the Form component, then it did not take values of inputs. Flow JSON editor did not detect it, because it is searching only for a "footer" element, but not the position of it. Now flow is working properly. You save my time!

Comment: That's great to hear. Please accept the answer so it may help others too